# What does the phrase "sets your offense should run" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

What does the phrase "sets your offense should run" mean in the following sentence from the description of a basketball simulation game:

> Every decision is under your control, which includes how often to
> practice to the **sets your offense should run**.

Comment: Bad grammar. It should read, "...how often to practice ____ the sets your offense should run." (omit second "to")

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about an ungrammatical sentence

Comment: @gotube I agree it is in telegram form but I do not think your reading is spot on. I think _how often to practice_ and _which sets to run_ are seen as limiting examples of the decisions the player or coach has to make.

Comment: @mdewey What does "how often to practice *to* the sets" mean? The sentence makes no sense because you cannot "practice to" something. Without the "to" it makes sense, and the question is unnecessary.

Comment: I think inserting _from_ after _includes_ makes sense.

Comment: @gotube:  The sentence is perfectly grammatical, what to you find wrong with it.

Comment: @Chenmunka Like I said, you practice *something*, not practice *to something*, unless you're practicing *something* to *music* or whatnot. Can you parse it for me or rephrase it so it makes sense?

Comment: @gotube: you're right. But I think it might just be a typo with that second "to". Removing that leaves it grammatically correct but still puzzling to an English learner and therefore worth keeping, I reckon. No?

Answer (score 2):

I had to read it a few times, and needed the context of sport to make any sense of it at all.

But there is an omitted "that": *the sets that your offense should run*.

This *that* may always be omitted, but it might have been helpful to keep it for clarity.

I have no idea what is meant by your offense running some sets, but presumably people familiar with the game will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The word "to" after "practice" looks like a typo. Are you sure it's in the original?

Assuming I'm right, then "sets your offense should run" can be parsed as follows. Note that as a Brit, I know next to nothing about baseball, but I can figure out the purpose the various words have

The word "sets" refers to some group of activities that can be performed, or "run".
The word "offense" refers, at any given time in a game, to one of the two competing sides. The other side is then the "defense". And the word "your" indicates that the instructions you have provided are meant to be read by the person in control of the "offense" side, or at least they are intended to apply to the reader's team when that team is designated as the offense (because in fact the offense/defense designations change throughout the course of the match).

Putting all of that together (and dropping the problematic word "to"), the sentence, including the phrase you are asking about,  might mean something like this:

> You are in control of every decision affecting your team. For example, while they are designated as offense, you must decide how often your team should perform practice sets.